# How to use for loop to simplify the code?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm not sure how to use for loop to simplify the code below so that it is less messy.

I had tried to use function to loop the code but it doesn't work for me.

```
group1 <- c(2,4,1,2,5,5,6,3,7,11)
group2 <- c(54,2,12,21,1,7,8,3,6,11)
group3 <- c(31,2,5,7,9,41,14,5,8,1)


vector1 <- c()
for(j in 1:3){
  x <- c()
  for(i in seq(j,length(group1),2)){
    x[i] <- group1[i]
  }
  vector1[j] <- mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)
}


vector2 <- c()
for(j in 1:3){
  y <- c()
  for(i in seq(j,length(group2),2)){
    y[i] <- group2[i]
  }
  vector2[j] <- mean(y,na.rm=TRUE)
}


vector3 <- c()
for(j in 1:3){
  z <- c()
  for(i in seq(j,length(group3),2)){
    z[i] <- group3[i]
  }
  vector3[j] <- mean(z,na.rm=TRUE)
}

All.vector <- as.numeric(cbind(vector1,vector2,vector3))
```

I hope the loop able to be flexible in term of number of vector. Which means sometimes it might be only have vector1 and vector2 and sometimes need to have vector1, vector2, and vector3 depends on number of group I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the groups in a data.frame or list and then use lapply to replace the loops. For this then you don't need to now how many groups there are, it will simply loop over all columns.

```
my_df <- data.frame(group1, group2, group3)

all_vec <- lapply(my_df, function(x) {
  vapply(1:3, FUN = function(j) mean(x[seq(j, length(x), 2)], na.rm = TRUE), FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))
})

unlist(all_vec)
# group11 group12 group13 group21 group22 group23 group31 group32 group33 
# 4.20    5.00    4.75   16.20    8.80    6.75   13.40   11.20    9.00
```

**Detailed explanation**
Let's have a look at your first loop, step by step.

```
vector1 <- c()
```

You intialize the vector, but it is better for performance to tell R how many elements to expect. So it would be better to write

```
vector1 <- numeric(3)
```

The same is true for your `x` inside the loop, however we can get rid if the inside loop by setting

```
x <- group1[seq(j,length(group1),2)]
```

instead of

```
  x <- c()
  for(i in seq(j,length(group1),2)){
    x[i] <- group1[i]
  }
```

With `vapply` we replace the outer loop

```
vector1 <- vapply(1:3, FUN = function(j) mean(group1[seq(j, length(group1), 2)], na.rm = TRUE), 
                 FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))
```

Now, we apply this `vapply` function to each column of our data.frame `my_df` with `lapply`. This returns a list for each column with the results. Using `unnest` flattens the list into a vector.

Comment: or `sapply(my_df, function(g) sapply(1:3, function(j) mean(g[seq(j,length(g),2)], na.rm=TRUE)))`

Comment: This then will yield a matrix and not exactly the desired output, but I think it would be better to use the matrix, so thanks ;)
However, I rather use vapply as it I have more control over the return values.

Comment: Thanks jogo and Kath! By the way, what does it means by FUN.Value=numeric(1) ?

Comment: `Fun.Value = numeric(1)` specifies that a single numeric number will be returned by the function.

Comment: What do you mean by single numeric number? Do you have any example?

Comment: Like `4.20` for the first calculation for the first group.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
vector1 <- c()
for(j in 1:3){
  x <- c()
  for(i in seq(j,length(group1),2)){
    x[i] <- group1[i]
    y[i] <- group2[i]
    z[i] <- group3[i]
  }
  vector1[j] <- mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)
  vector2[j] <- mean(y,na.rm=TRUE)
  vector3[j] <- mean(y,na.rm=TRUE)
}
```